# how get each value out side of for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

i have have two loop ,nested loops,i need to get each value of first to outside.

```js
var shift="";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   
   shift = "shift"+i;
   for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
         
        //my code
      }
}

console.log(shift);
```

i need to get each value of shift,ex:shift 1,shift 2,shift 3,shift 4,shift 5.
but i can not get it.it give only last value, shift 5

Comment: Push to an array?

Comment: `var shift = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      shift.push("shift" + i);
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        //my code
      }
    }`

Comment: You can also just concatenate by `shift += " shift"+i`  if you need a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are printing the values outside the scope of the first loop, and this is the reason you are not getting all the values. Do it this way.

```
var shift="";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

   shift = "shift"+i;
   for(var j=0;j<3;j++){


      }
console.log(shift);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

console.log(shift) should be inside loop

```
var shift="";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

   shift = "shift"+i;
   for(var j=0;j<3;j++){

        //my code
      }
console.log(shift);
}
```